# Rigify/Armature - additional bones cause unwanted deformation

Tags: armature, rigify

I made simple humanoid low-poly character/model for testing/prototyping.

[image]

Character has extra "weapon" bones attached to palms. The idea is to parent weapon objects to those bones, which would allow me to rotate blades/guns/whatever independently from hands.

[image]

However, once I create "rigified" rig, rotating those bones (which show up at FK layer, by the way) cause unwanted deformation of fingers.

[image]

I checked mesh in weight paint mode, this is not problem with weight, actual skeleton is being deformed. (It is visible in the last screen).

Why does this happen, how do I fix this, and is there alternative/better way to make "weapon" bone?

I do suspect that "weapon bone" somehow interferes with inverse kinematics, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Model is animated with inverse kinematics, with all FK/IK sliders set to IK on arms/legs.

I created weapon bones by selecting "hand", extruding it twice, then deleting middle connecting bone.

Aside from having extra bones for weapons, it is pretty much stock metarig with slightly adjusted bone positions.

I'm using 64bit blender 2.74 on windows 7.

---

[Here is file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7ur4bsizy3kz0i/girl_anim_upload.7z?dl=0) with the rig (without geometry/animations). It is saved with weapon bone selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ORG-palm.0# finger bones (the base ones) have constraints copying transforms from the ORG-weapon bone.

The constraints were probably targeting different bone originally (hand probably).

Delete those constraints or re-target them to ORG-hand.

Why don't you use Child-Of constraining for picking up objects/weapons? I think you don't need the weapon bone, this seems very non-standard.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. That was obviously a glitch created when I built the rig. Also, I do need weapon bone, (they're usually called "Prop Bones", though). You see, when you make sword-fighting animations or melee weapon animations in general, weapon does not normally precisely follow the hand. For example, you could take a look at this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-lNEjSzJTs or just google "stick kata" on youtube. So, if you need swappable sword model in game engine, your animation set will need "prop" or "weapon" bone, with animated position/rotation.

Comment: @SigTerm game engine clears it out, yep you need an extra bone for that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your bone has copies of some properties of the hand bone, from which you extruded, that cause the problem.
Try this: In edit mode delete the Weapon bone; shift A add a new bone, which will be placed a the 3D cursor position. Place the new bone where you need, then select a Parent bone (maybe the hand bone) Ctrl P - keep offset.

See if, this way, everything is OK. If not, you should upload the .blend file, to be analized!

Comment: "copies of some properties" Would be nice to know which ones. You see, I animated rigify rig despite having that glitch, and right now I'd rather not redo those animations after changing original metarig.

Comment: You will loose only the animation relative to the bone you will delete, everything else will remain. Whitout the .blend file it's difficult to make ipothesis.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to delete rigified rig and then recreate it from original metarig? I think doing that would kill animation tracks...

Comment: There's no need to recreate the whole rig. Even in that case, if the new recreated bones have the same name of the previous rig, you don't loose anything

Comment: I've added file with the rig, if you're interested.